# Show powerline git information in dired

Tags: dired, terminal-emacs, powerline, vc-mode

[Powerline](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline) shows git branch information for a buffer that are under version control `vc-mode`. Only when `vc-mode` is set for a buffer the Git branch information is displayed. When inside `dired` there is no Version Control information shown. Is there a way to enable vc-mode for dired so that at least the branch information is shown without needing to patch powerline.el ?

To visualize what I mean: This is the powerline for buffers that have vc-mode set:
[image]
The powerline for the dired buffer has no vc-mode set and the branch information is missing:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to patch [powerline.el](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/blob/master/powerline.el#L477) using:

```
modified   .emacs.d/lisp/lib/powerline.el
@@ -473,14 +473,27 @@ static char * %s[] = {
                 'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map
                             'mouse-1 'mode-line-widen))))

+
+(require 'vc-git)
+
 ;;;###autoload (autoload 'powerline-vc "powerline")
 (defpowerline powerline-vc
-  (when (and (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)) vc-mode)
+  (cond
+   ((and (symbolp 'major-mode) (string-equal major-mode 'dired-mode)
+    (vc-git-root default-directory))
+    (progn
+      (vc-mode-line default-directory 'Git)
+      (format " %s%s"
+         (char-to-string #xe0a0)
+         (format-mode-line '(vc-mode vc-mode)))))
+   ((and (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)) vc-mode)
     (if (and window-system (not powerline-gui-use-vcs-glyph))
         (format-mode-line '(vc-mode vc-mode))
       (format " %s%s"
               (char-to-string #xe0a0)
-              (format-mode-line '(vc-mode vc-mode))))))
+              (format-mode-line '(vc-mode vc-mode))))
+    )
+   ))

 ;;;###autoload (autoload 'powerline-encoding "powerline")
 (defpowerline powerline-encoding
```

This makes revision appear inside dired. Using `vc-git-root` to verify it is a git directory and `(vc-mode-line default-directory 'Git)` to initialize `vc-mode`. I wonder weather there is a better solution than this?